# Replacing text in excel from a static table

Tags: excel

I have a report that is sent to me daily that only supplies IP addresses and would like to create a macro that would look up the address to host conversion from another table (external to the excel sheet report). So that when its executed, the IP address would be replaced with the actual hostname.

```
Date/Time Detected    Source IP Address       Destination IP Address
6/19/2013 15:46       172.16.16.40            172.16.4.10
6/19/2013 15:46       172.16.16.40             *
6/19/2013 15:02       172.16.16.40             *
6/19/2013 15:02       172.16.16.40             *
6/19/2013 15:02       172.16.16.40             *
6/19/2013 15:02       172.16.16.40             *
```

In this example, I would have a table that would have an IP address and Host address (from a dns export table), that I would like to do a replace Source IP with it's hostname from my daily reports.  The dns table is static, the daily reports would be populated with a replace IP with hostname from the static dns table.

Comment: Need a bit more info. Is the "external table" itself an excel workbook, or another kind of file? What is the format of that file? The `VLOOKUP` function may well be your friend... but you need to show the other table.

Comment: the external table isn't setup yet... depending upon an answer here it would be created.  I can pull a dns report and generate the table to a csv file, txt file, etc.  The daily report is always sent in excel.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` works but I've personally started using `INDEX` and `MATCH`.  It's a little more flexible and you can do some fancier things.

Comment: No, don't mind adding a column.. its just that reading the IP doesn't tell me a thing, Kinda like the movie the Matrix :) I need to see the hostname, and I could always hide the "reports" colums I dont want to see..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a very simple example of how to do this:

[image]

Right now (to make it easier to make the picture) the DNStable is a named range (green background) in the same sheet - but it could be in another sheet/workbook. The `VLOOKUP` function attempts to find an exact match (fourth argument `FALSE` means "exact match") between the first argument (the "Source IP Address") and the first column in that table; it returns the value in column 2 if found, or `#N/A` if not found.

To do the same thing when the DNS lookup is a different file, use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,DNSlookup.xlsx!DNStable,2, FALSE)
```

Where the `DNSlookup.xlsx` file contains a named range `DNStable` as before:
[image]

As long as that file is open in your copy of Excel, you're good - they don't have to be in the same file. Now copy this formula into cell D2, and drag it all the way down. Cool trick: if you select the cell, then double-click the little "dragbox" in the bottom right-hand corner, it will automatically fill all the way down (as many cells as there are cells immediately to the left of it). Try it!

Note - if you now close both the DNS lookup file and this file, and then open it again, you will get a warning about "updating external links". At that point you will see the formula has changed to something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'X:\code\DNSlookup.xlsx'!DNStable,2, FALSE)
```

As you can see, it's created a link to the location where the other file is kept - but it also kept the value of the last successful lookup.

This ought to work for you.

Comment: Cool.. so in the example, if I wanted to have it look in another excel file,(my DNS list), how would that be setup? Can it read the excel file from a network share for example, or would it be easier to create the named range into a blank sheet, (somewhere not to be overwritten by a copy/ paste) and then paste the report excel information into this new sheet at a predefined starting point?

Comment: @JMurray - I have updated my answer to address your question.